# How to determine, the verb I have chosen for making a sentence, that is transitive or intransitive?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verbs

A lot of transitive and intransitive verbs out there but I want to know, Is there any rule? that can help us to  determine it.

Comment: Hopefully you know the [difference between transitive and intransitive verbs](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/transitive-and-intransitive-verbs). Using these definitions, find the verb in the sentence. If the verb requires a _direct object_ (i.e. the verb cannot be by itself/the action must be done to something else), then it is a transitive verb. For example, in the sentence _Bob bought three apples_, _bought_ is transitive because it takes a direct object; you use money **to buy something else** (apples). For an intransitive verb, it may stand by itself, such as _Jill **dances**_.

Comment: Another good idea would be to use a dictionary if you struggle; it doesn't hurt. Speakers at every level require clarification from time to time.

Comment: Thank you. I can understand , though there are some ambiguities in mind.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent answer in the comments:

"Hopefully you know the [difference between transitive and intransitive verbs](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/transitive-and-intransitive-verbs). Using these definitions, find the verb in the sentence. If the verb requires a direct object (i.e. the verb cannot be by itself/the action must be done to something else), then it is a transitive verb. For example, in the sentence Bob bought three apples, bought is transitive because it takes a direct object; you use money *to buy something else* (apples). For an intransitive verb, it may stand by itself, such as *Jill dances*." – Kman3

"Another good idea would be to use a dictionary if you struggle; it doesn't hurt. Speakers at every level require clarification from time to time." – Kman3